# RFID protected wallet

Tags: rfid

Is there something I can put behind my bus pass in my rfid protected wallet so that it will scan on the busses. At the moment I have to take it out to use it.

Comment: What is the point of using a RFID protected wallet (or putting your bus pass in it) if you don't want the protection?

Answer (score 2):

Since you have to take it out of your wallet for it to work, I'm going to assume that your bus pass uses an RFID.  In that case the answer is very straightforward:

### No

If you have an RFID blocking wallet, then it won't let RFID's inside it work.  That's pretty much the point.  The only way to make your bus pass work while inside your wallet is to switch to a non-RFID blocking wallet (or remove whatever is inside the wallet that blocks RF waves).

In that case though it will no longer be an RFID blocking wallet.  It seems you're looking for an RFID blocking wallet that doesn't actually block RFIDs.  Such a thing doesn't exist.